# "style" position

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the below sentence, can I say "style of charm"? I find many examples used in this way, for example, a style of management, a style of architecture, etc.

> His essays have a charm of style that can't be found in other writers.

Comment: "style of management" or "management style". "style of charm" or "charm style". Though I have no idea what "charm style" would mean as I have never heard such a phrase.

Comment: On a side note, there's a totally different meaning between "style of charm" (what you asked) and "charm of style" (what you gave as an example).

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin, could you tell me the difference between style of charm and charm of style? thanks a lot.

Comment: Finally found a way to understand both phrases. I added it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can; as pointed out in V.V.'s answer. Going with your example, you can go with either one, that is:

> His essays have **a charm of style** that can't be found in other writers.

or:

> His essays have **a style of charm** that can't be found in other writers.

Though I still like to emphasis that the meaning is still different. "Charm of style" means that the style is charming, while "style of charm" means that charming is the style itself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both phrases describing the writer's style.**Charm of style** (beauty of style) means a distinguished captivating style the writer has. It has the power of attracting or fascinating others.
A style of charm is also possible meaning a *pleasant* style.Just some examples :

> His collectible artwork captures **a style of charm** and warmth that is Michael's trademark, recognized throughout the world.
>
> His geological writings, moreover, are marked by great **charm of style**; and he virtually formulated a new aesthetic for the startling scenery of the Grand Canyon country.

Comment: Thank you for this. Never knew that the phrase "charm of style" actually meant something. However, shouldn't "charm of style" and "style of charm" have different meaning?

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin, I included it into my answer

Comment: Thanks. I actually edit my answer to better reflect this new information from you.